# Laravel Eloquent resets primary key value after save() called

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and when I insert model, primary key id column is somehow reset to 0. What's happening is below.

```
$fooModel = new FooModel();
$fooModel->foo_id = 123;
$fooModel->foo_title = 'foo';
echo($fooModel->foo_id); //123
$fooModel->save();
echo($fooModel->foo_id); //0
```

The data is successfully inserted on MySQL database, but foo_id column is reset to 0 in PHP. If it's an autoincrement column, I know it'll be updated by the next sequence value, but this column is not. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
class FooModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'foo_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'foo_id';
    protected $guarded = ['foo_id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'foo_id' => 'integer'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Are you getting other fields like `updated_at` have values or same issue of resetting, or it is only for primary key field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved. I needed to declare "public $incrementing = false;" in my Model class.

```
class FooModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'foo_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'foo_id';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $guarded = ['foo_id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'foo_id' => 'integer'
    ];
}
```

The default setting for $incrementing is true. That's why laravel set the id column to 0.

```
abstract class Model {

    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = true;

}
```

Comment: OMG, you've saved me from chasing down a rabbit hole

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$fooModel = $fooModel->save();
echo($fooModel->foo_id);
```

or

```
 $fooModel = $fooModel->save();
    echo($fooModel->id);
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. It was about INSERT not UPDATE. When I call save() for UPDATE, the foo_id column value is there, but when I call save() for INSERT, the foo_id column value is reset to 0.

Comment: I tried your code, but the error "Trying to get property of non-object" happened.

Comment: just try what is out put `$fooModel = $fooModel->save();
echo($fooModel);` i guess after save nee to get 
`echo($fooModel->id);`

Comment: When save() is called, boolean value will be returned to tell if data was successfully inserted/updated.

Comment: echo($fooModel->id); also outputs 0.